# Synchronize ALL timeline entries during migration of questions

Tags: feature-request, migration, timeline

Consider [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122427) on webapps.se.com, which is actually the migrated version of [this original version](https://superuser.com/revisions/1377543/1) on superuser.com. Looking at the current [timeline of the migrated version](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/122427/timeline), it shows that:

- The question was first posted "yesterday" (obviousy, on superuser.com).
- A 1st answer (still on superuser.com) was posted 13 hours ago.
- The question was migrated (to webapps.se.com) 11 hours ago .
- A 2nd answer (on webapps.se.com) was posted 6 hours ago.

The above info seems OK (by looking at it to the timeline on webapps.se.com).

However, if you look at the [timeline of this question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/posts/1377543/timeline), then there is no more entry for that 1st answer (still on superuser.com) that was posted 13 hours ago. So it appears like that specific timeline entry was MOVED to the corresponding [timeline on webapps.se.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/122427/timeline).

It seems to me that **the specific timeline entry for that 1st answer should still be included in the [timeline of this question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/posts/1377543/timeline)**. So that it would look like a COPY instead of a MOVE of that timeline entry.

Similarly, about the edits applied to the original question (still on superuser.com, about 11 hours ago, a bit before the migration happened): it seems that **there should be some sort of entry (also a COPY of it?) in the [timeline on webapps.se.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/122427/timeline)** (where currently there is nothing in its timeline about those edits before the migration).

PS: for the 2nd answer (on webapps.se.com), there is nothing to mention in the timeline on superuser.com (since nothing happened about that answer on superuser.com).

Comment: I think it's a policy issue with site admins!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen what kind of policy do you mean, is it documented anywhere?

Comment: A software design policy I think from the looks of things. And I don't know of any where it's documented! A site admin so make this clear why that is used!

Comment: The timeline entry for the answer *does* still exist on Super User, but it is only visible to 10k users because it is deleted (due to the migration).

Comment: @animuson even though that might somehow explain the issue for that 1st answer, IMO that first answer is to be considered as migrated (also), not "deleted". In doing so, one can separate really deleted answers (not shown in the timeline) from migrated answers (to be shown). Which would also make it behave similar to what is shown in the timeline for the migrated (not "deleted") question.

Comment: @Pierre There are easy ways to tell whether an answer was migrated or not by just looking at the timestamps. As well, the question stub on the old site will eventually be deleted automatically also, so putting in a bunch of work to somehow improve a timeline that will only be visible for a month isn't a very high priority. Most of us would rather just drop the migration system than put more work into it. *shrugs*